# LU decomposition - what can we say about A given L and U.

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it true that if $A=LU$ then if L (lower triangular) and U (upper triangular) both have all nonzero entries on the diagonal then A has all nonzero entries on the diagonal? I think this is true but I am not 100% sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not true. A counterexample
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$

The correct statement is: If $A$ is invertible, then it admits $LU$ decomposition if and only if all its leading principal [minors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)) are nonzero.